# Converting JSON with inconsistent field names to Java objects with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON to convert a JSON file into Java objects. The file contains two type of JSON entities, type one is `PKeyColumn` and type two is named `FKeyColumn`. Here are two examples:

```
        "PKeyColumn": {
            "pk_BlogVersions": [
                "Blog_Id",
                "Version_Id"
            ]
        },
        "FKeyColumn": [{
            "ForeignKeyColumns": {
                "Blog_Id": "Id"
            },
            "ReferenceTable": "Blogs"
        }],
```

I know I should make a class called `PKeyColumn` and `FKeyColumn`, but I get stuck after that. For `FKeyColumn` I think I could make `ForeignKeyColumns` an inner class and have a single `ForeignKeyColumn` object and a `ReferenceTable` object be the members of the FKeyColumn class. However, the problem is that the fields the `ForeignKeyColumns` object contains vary from object to object.

For `PKeyColumn`, the trouble is that the name of the array it contains varies from `PKeyColumn` to `PKeyColumn`, so I can't just say that `PKeyColumn` contains an `ArrayList<String>` named `pk_BlogVersions` and be done with it.

Any suggestions on how to get around this issue?

Comment: `Table` class with two fields: `PKeyColumn pkeyColumn`, `List<ForeignKey> foreignKeys`. --- `ForeignKey` class with two fields: `List<ForeignKeyColumn> foreignKeyColumns`, `String referenceTable`. --- And so on. `@SerializedName` as needed to control JSON names.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would fix the issue of having different inconsistent keys. I might have one ForeignKeyColumns that contains "Blog_Id": "Id", but the next one might be "Version_Id": 1234

Comment: Hmmm... Try changing the `foreignKeyColumns` field of the `ForeignKey` class to be a `Map<String, String>`. Don't know if GSON will do maps like that, but it should.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think that will work for FKeyColumn, but how about for PKeyColumn? The name of the inner array isn't static. I might have `"pk_BlogVersions` for one but `"pk_BlogPosts` for another. Is there a way to ignore the name just get the data it contains?

Comment: `pkeyColumn` would then be a `Map<String, List<String>>`.